# Can i use Straight blade connector for garbage disposal under sink

Tags: wiring, garbage-disposal, building-regulations, connectors, cord-and-plug

The current garbage disposal is hardwired , I am replacing it with new one which comes with cord . can u use cord connector (Straight blade connector) [image: Here is the image of plug i want to use]

is it ok to use this setup ans be under building codes ?[image][image]

Comment: What are you trying to put the cord cap (that's what the thing in your picture is called) *on*? Why can't you whack a box, single receptacle, and faceplate in instead?

Comment: The plug of garbage disposal will connect to cordcap .I can add receptacle, But this seem easy and cost effective to do without much tools  plus receptacle should be surface mount which costs more. Plus I may have to use gfci I guess due to proximity to water source.

Comment: Really there doesn't seem to be any conventional way to use that *cord connector* for the job you are describing. If you are connecting to an energized wire with exposed  "male" prongs (like a *cord cap*), well... we call that a **widow-maker**.

Comment: @ShivakiranNeelagiri -- that cordcap needs to be connected to a cable of somesort, or else your garbage disposal will sit there doing nothing :P

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Added  pic . Please advise

Comment: Is your plan to put that cord cap on the end of the existing wiring from your old disposal?

Comment: Putting a cord cap on a piece of Romex would be a code violation. If you want it to be plugged in a connector is required like 3phase mentioned. If you want direct wire follow the cord back to its junction box on the machine and that is where you could make the connection with /to the house wiring